# What is the difference between order id, increment id and quote id?

Tags: magento2, cart, orders, quote, increment-id

I observed that all the above term's value are different which I thought to be same.

```
echo $orderId = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
echo $qid = $order->getQuoteId();
$order_data= $order->getData();
echo $increment_id = $order_data['increment_id'];
```

Above code outputs **orderId: 32, QuoteId: 41 and incremenId: 52**. Why are these three values different and what they mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is:

- `order_id` is the internal Magento order ID (database table auto increment id)
- `increment_id` is the    ID which you communicate to your
  customer
- `quote_id` is the internal quote id (When user add product to cart those are added in quote , after checkout success quote is transferred to order)

**Why they are different**

`order_id` and `quote_id` needs to be different because they refers to the different table(or different object, `order_id` refers to order object while `quote_id` refers to quote object), increment id is different as it allows you to show a different order-id with prefix to the customer

Comment: And why should they be different?

Comment: Please edit your answer with this info.